# Android populate listview from arraylist Error

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to populate a `listview` in my android App (android studio) from a list to which I dynamically added Strings.

First, the list is declared as an attribute of the activity:

```
private List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then, I have the class where the method `populatelist()` is called. There are other methods called in it, but they all work fine, `populatelist()` is the only method that gives me an error:

```
  private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {               

                    parse(message);
                    populatelist();
                }



            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

And this is the method itself:

```
public void populatelist() {
    //    String[] myitems = {"World Weather Online","Open Weather Map","Weather"};
        Log.d("Matcher", "Populate! Test 1");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.items,R.id.textting,your_array_list);
        Log.d("Matcher", "Populate! Test 2");
        ListView list;
        Log.d("Matcher", "Populate! Test 3");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.services);
        Log.d("Matcher", "Populate! Test 4");
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("Matcher", "Populate! Test 5");

    }
```

All the logs print except the last one "Test 5". When I run my app, I get the following error:

```
07-19 21:13:32.399    1575-1591/com.example.othmane.servicefinder E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.othmane.servicefinder, PID: 1575
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6247)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:2855)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:679)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:679)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:679)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:679)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:679)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:679)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:679)
            at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9603)
            at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:6741)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:722)
            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:488)
            at com.example.othmane.servicefinder.MainActivity.populatelist(MainActivity.java:277)
            at com.example.othmane.servicefinder.MainActivity$SendMessage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:100)
            at com.example.othmane.servicefinder.MainActivity$SendMessage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Does anyone see any mistake of how I try to populate the list ? I followed a tutorial to do it, but I don't know why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Read the logcat and you will see the answer:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. at
```

The error is caused by you are trying to populate view in the background thread. In order to perform work in the main thread, you need to call onPostExecute method.

Here is the example from one of my app:

```
    public class FetchArtistData extends AsyncTask<String,Void, List<Artist>> {
    private static final String TAG="FetchArtistData";
    @Override
    protected List<Artist> doInBackground(String... params) {
        SpotifyApi api=new SpotifyApi();
        SpotifyService spotify=api.getService();
        ArtistsPager results=spotify.searchArtists(params[0]);
        List<Artist> list=results.artists.items;
        Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Artist> artists) {
        mArtistList=(ArrayList<Artist>)artists;
        Log.d(TAG,Integer.toString(mArtistList.size()));
        updateAdapter(mArtistList);
    }
}
```

Noticed that I update the view in onPostExecute.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't have the error anymore, but the list is still empty

Comment: can you also post the code for your_array_list and parse(message). It appears to me that you may have implemented them incorrectly and as a result the your_array_list is empty. Typically, I would call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged or write my own updateAdapter(ArrayList) in onPostExecute method to repopulate the listview with the new data.

Comment: Let's try to create ArrayAdapter onCreateView, update your_array_list to reflect the new set of data and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged on onPostExecute. Hope this help

Comment: After trying different things, I found out that the populatelist() method does not wait for the previous method to finish, hence, the arraylist is still empty when I try to populate listview. I am still confused !! I can't spend a lot of time on this since it is only a small part of my work, so I will use a temporary solution (use a while() that keeps running until the arraylist size is not 0), but I hope someone will find the answer to help whoever might have the same problem !